# UI.Bootsrap conflict with AngularJS password matching

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

The problem stands as follows: I have a fully working angularjs code for password matching:

```
var app = angular.module('ngMatch', []);
    app.directive('match', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                match: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    var modelValue = ctrl.$modelValue || ctrl.$$invalidModelValue;
                    return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(modelValue)) || scope.match === modelValue;
                }, function(currentValue) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

But addition of ui.bootstrap for tooltips on input:

```
<input id="password" type="password"
                   tooltip="Your password should contain at least one digit, one capital and special symbol, should have the length from 8 to 20 symbols"
                   tooltip-trigger="focus"
                   tooltip-placement="top"
                   class="form-control"
                   name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"
                   ng-model="password"
                   pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
                   minlength="8" maxlength="20"
                   required>

<input id="confirm-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="confirm_password" data-match="password" required>
```

Results in scope.match become "undefined".
Already tried to rename the directive from "match" to something different, but this didn't work.
Also found the following issue: https://github.com/interval-braining/angular-input-match/issues/1, which corresponds to my issue but not showing any errors.

I'd also like to clarify: The issue shows up ONLY when we add 'ui.bootstrap' to the list of dependencies:

```
angular.module('ModuleName', [
        'ui.router',
        ...
        'vcRecaptcha',
        'ui.bootstrap'
    ])
```

And it doesn't matter whether we actually use it or not, but when it's added we're getting some other 'scope' (without 'match' variable) for unknown reason.

What we can do to make our scopes even more isolated?
Any help is appreciated, I have spent more than 7 hours, trying to resolve this conflict...

Comment: I don't see in your example where you are using this directive?